# Allocating space to data structure on need basis in C++

Tags: c++

I have a data structure of the following form:

```
class A{
    unsigned t;
    bool isPresent;
    map<unsigned,unsigned> isPresentA;
    map<unsigned,unsigned> isPresentB; 
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    A a;
    cout<<"size of map="<<sizeof(a)<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Now when `a.isPresent` is true, then only I store values in `a.isPresentA` and `a.isPresentB`. And when `a.isPresent` is false, then my map's `a.isPresentA` and `a.isPresentB` are empty. However, I see that although I don't store values in `a.isPresentA` and `a.isPresentB`, still its size is 104. Is there some way in C++ so that I may allocate space to `a.isPresentA` and `a.isPresentB` only on need basis (i.e. when `a.isPresent` is true), rather than explicitly allocating storage space to them.

I am storing millions of objects of class A, therefore the size of class A is a concern for me.

I am using gcc version: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.4-6ubuntu2) 4.6.4

Comment: Even if you store thousands of items in a map the size you get from `sizeof` will not change.  The map object does not grow as you add items.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I am storing millions of objects of class A, therefore the size of class A is a concern to me.

Comment: `sizeof(a)` returns the size of the the class A, no matter what you store in the maps (here it'll be a dozen of bytes)

Comment: In C++, like in most languages I know, every object of a class always has the same size. If you want to save something, then put the two maps in another class, and store a `unique_ptr` to that in `A`.

Comment: Also, rather than `isPresent`, consider using `boost::optional`.

Comment: How about: `class A { unsigned t; Storage * optional_storage; }`. Now give `a.optional_storage == nullptr` the semantics of "not present", and otherwise "a pointer to the relevant maps".

Comment: @GiulioFranco I do not know about unique_ptr  can you please illustrate with the help of an example

Comment: @StegVerner : or you Google and study it

Comment: @StegVerner same as suggested by Bas, just using `unique_ptr` rather than `shared_ptr`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Comment: @GiulioFranco: I believe using boost/std `optional` would effectively just wrap `isPresent`, `isPresentA` and `isPresentB` without moving their data out of `class A` i.e. from memory it doesn't create the optional data on the heap, rather - it keeps an internal sufficiently-memory-aligned buffer ready to placement-`new` objects into.

Comment: @TonyD i meant `optional<unique_ptr<ClassWithTwoMaps>>`. `optional` doesn't move things out. It only abstracts the `isPresent` concept in a more complex/complete way.

Comment: @GiulioFranco: oh - well, that'd be counter-productive given it will swell `A` with an extra boolean of some sort, and the `unique_ptr` has a convenient `operator bool()` anyway.  The inherent sentinel value of `nullptr` should suffice to replace `isPresent`.  I.e. we're just talking about Kerrek's suggestion above with a smart- rather than raw-pointer.

Comment: @TonyD you're right.

Comment: On a different note: Do you have to use gcc 4.6.4? You might very well get speed and maybe even space improvements by just switching to a newer version of gcc and recompiling your code. Not to mention all the additional c++11/14 - features you could use then.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an instance of class A, the two maps are automatically allocated. To counter this, you can make pointers out of them:

```
class A{
    unsigned t;
    bool isPresent;
    map<unsigned,unsigned>* isPresentA;
    map<unsigned,unsigned>* isPresentB; 
};
```

However, you need to allocate (and delete!) them yourself now! A safer option is using std::shared_ptr:

```
class A{
    unsigned t;
    bool isPresent;
    std::shared_ptr<map<unsigned,unsigned>> isPresentA;
    std::shared_ptr<map<unsigned,unsigned>> isPresentB; 
};
```

You still need to initialize them, but at least you won't have to worry about deleting them. You should add a constructor or initializer function to your class to do this:

```
class A{
    A(bool is_present) {
        isPresent = is_present;
        if (isPresent) {
            isPresentA = std::make_shared<map<unsigned int, unsigned int>>();
            isPresentB = std::make_shared<map<unsigned int, unsigned int>>();
        }
    }
    unsigned t;
    bool isPresent;
    std::shared_ptr<map<unsigned,unsigned>> isPresentA;
    std::shared_ptr<map<unsigned,unsigned>> isPresentB; 
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but I am getting the following error...‘shared_ptr’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type.

Comment: Why use `shared_ptr` when a simple `unique_ptr` does the job ?

Comment: @Quentin You're right, I'm just too used to using shared_ptr objects myself.

Comment: @StegVerner You might need to add an include to <memory>. Whenever you get errors like this, just google "c++ shared_ptr" and you'll see what source the class comes from ;)

Comment: @StegVerner: you can google `std::shared_ptr site:cppreference.com` and see which header you need to `#include`.  Good way to resolve such problems.

Comment: @TonyD It does not work as I am using gcc 4.6. Is there some solution which might work with gcc 4.6

Comment: @StegVerner: Have you tried to compile it with the `-std=c++0x` flag?

Comment: @StegVerner: Mike's suggestion's sound.  Failing that, consider getting it from boost, or use raw pointers (very carefully).  You can't code your own in the style of `unique_ptr` sensibly without C++11 (need support for "move" semantics from your containers).  Avoid `auto_ptr` (e.g. `vector<A>` resizing would break, most Standard algorithms that copy elements would corrupt your container/array etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want without complicating your class by using unique_ptr:

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>

class A {
    unsigned t;
    unique_ptr<map<unsigned, unsigned>> isPresentA;
    unique_ptr<map<unsigned, unsigned>> isPresentB;
};
```

you can check for presence by using isPresentA or B directly:

```
if (a.isPresentA) {
}
```

or wrap it into some class method alla `bool isPresent();`

A somewhat more refined version might look like this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <map>

using namespace std;


class A {
    struct OptinalParts {
        map<unsigned, unsigned> a;
        map<unsigned, unsigned> b;
    };
    unsigned t;
    unique_ptr<OptinalParts> optional;

public:
    A() :t(0),optional(nullptr){};
    A(bool initState):t(0) {
        makePresent(initState);
    }
    bool isPresent() {
        return (bool)optional;
    }
    void makePresent(bool set) {
        if (set && !isPresent())  {             
            optional.reset(new OptinalParts);                   
        }
        else {
            optional.reset(nullptr); 
        }
    }
    /*
    * accessors
    */
};
```

You probably have to replace any occurence of `nullptr` by `NULL`

Comment: I am using gcc version 4.6, will unique_ptr work with it

Comment: @Steg Verner: I believe yes, as long as you compile with the flag "-std=c++0x"

Comment: @StegVerner for full C++11 support you'll need GCC 4.8.2. Maybe 4.7 is sufficient for `unique_ptr`, but I doubt 4.6 is.

Comment: @Quentin: As far as I can tell, it was already introduced in 4.4.7,: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/changes.html

Comment: @MikeMB I thought 4.6 was much older. Oh well.